PF rule not working on macOS Sonoma 14.6.1
I am running a Quarto book (which I believe is just a Jupyter notebook under the hood) and I want to access it from my iPad browser. I have a firewall running on my Mac so the only way I could see getting this to work besides ssh port forwarding (which does work fine) is to add a PF rule.
So after reading up in this I created a file with my rule (my.conf) and run the following in a terminal:
cat /etc/pf.conf my.conf | sudo /sbin/pfctl -Ef -

Checking the rules I see it seems to have opened the port:
~ sudo pfctl -s rules                                                                                        No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled 
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
pass on en0 proto tcp from any to any port = 6666 flags S/SA keep state

Unfortunately, when I test it out on another Mac, the port is still blocked Isis.local is the server with the port I want open:
nc Isis.local 6666 -vvvv
nc: connectx to Isis.local port 6666 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connectx to Isis.local port 6666 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
.
.
nc: connectx to Isis.local port 6666 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out

I checked on the server Mac and the port is definitely open and available on en0.
I even tried adding a rule to allow all incoming local traffic:
pass on en0 from <local> to any flags S/SA keep state

But no joy.
I also checked on the serving Mac that pf is enabled.
As for why port forwarding isn’t good enough, even with the various iPad apps that support it, it’s not stable enough. Ultimately I want to do this remotely but if I can’t even get it to work on my local network…
I should note that the server Mac is a laptop and en0 is the wifi network although I don’t know if that makes a difference.

Can you say more about the firewall you're running on your Mac, that caused you to go down this path? Are you saying you were already running a custom PF configuration that was blocking this, so you're just trying to get PF to stop blocking it? Or were you running some other firewall, such as macOS's app firewall? I ask because I'm thinking this might be an XY problem, where the real underlying question might be "How can I make firewall x (where x ≠ pf) allow access to my Quarto web service?"

I am using the Mac OS X firewall which comes built in. In general if you turn on Mac OS X firewall, you need to provide access to specific applications through the settings. If you want to give access to a specific port you need to do it through the command line as indicated, using pf, at least from everything I have read available on the topic. I did give access to quarto but that didn’t help.

@Spiff your comment got me thinking. I gave Jupyter access, no help. I had Norton installed (for company testing purposes) with firewall off since I use the Mac one. I uninstalled it completely. But it didn’t help with port access. That did help with another problem: after a day my ssh stops working with kex-exchange error. Previously I have to reinstall OS X to fix that. Uninstalling Norton did the same :) It seems Norton is a virus as many claim and you should only use open source malware scanners. Tl;dr I am quite confident that Apple firewall is the only one working on my Mac right now

Ok problem solved, sort of. As @Spiff helped me realize this is not a network/firewall issue but network/application issue. Turns out even when I shut off firewall I can’t access it. It seems this has to do with fact that underlying quarto is Jupyter and that by default only listens on the loop back. Now I have to fiddle with Jupyter configuration….
